# How does combination selector "AB" works? where "A" and "B" is any selector?

Tags: html, css, selector

I have been studying "combination selector" using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors). It means that by placing A and B together (where A and B can be any selector), it select any element matching both A and B at the same time.

Could someone please explain how it actually works?

I understand how other combination selector i.e. "A B", "A > B", "A + B" and "A ~ B" works, but is stack on how "AB" works.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means an element would need to have both classes to be matched. For example

```
<div class="A B">
```

This would be selected by the rule

```
.A.B { //rules }
```

The class names in the element must be separated by a space, but the CSS selector would not have a space between the class names. That would be the second case in your table example, and a different situation.

Comment: oh, that makes perfect sense now! thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. IMO the MDN table would be clearer if they prefaced the `A` and `B` with a period like in the real world.

Comment: thats true. I even tried to place "div" and "p" tag together lol silly me

Comment: @j08691 Totally agree, MDN like many tutorials seems more designed to be a refresher/reference for people who already know this stuff than an actual teaching tool.

Answer (score 2):

You take any two selectors, and you write them together without anything between them.

For example, let *A* be the type selector for `<a>` elements and *B* be the `:focus` pseudo-class selector.

```
a:focus
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comments! now I understand!